# in c# global connection to be used in all classes

Tags: c#, sqlconnection

I've a connection string saved to `Properties.Settings.Default`, i need to use an sql connection in all classes without having to declare it everytime, so how should it be declared?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually don't need to use a single `SqlConnection` everywhere. A better approach would be to create a class to manage you data access. Typically this is the duty of your Data Access Layer (DAL). DAL is a set of classes that handle all the database related stuff.

A very simple class for this purpose could be something like this:

```
public class DatabaseManager
{
    private static DatabaseManager _instance;
    private DatabaseManager()
    {
    }

    static DatabaseManager()
    {
        _instance = new DatabaseManager();
    }

    public DatabaseManager Instance
    {
        get { return _instance; }
    }

    private string GetConnectionString()
    {
        return Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString;
    }

    public SqlConnection CreateConnection()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());
    }
}
```

You can extend this class to contain another methods to execute your queries.

I highly recommend you to use an [ORM (Object-Relational Mapper)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) like [Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/ef.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

It can be done with the help of STATIC variable in any class

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you instantiate a new object pass to its constructor a reference to that connection.

Answer (score 1):

I've have something similar set up in an old project like so.
It's worth noting that you should always be using a new `SqlConnection` for all your operations, because of [connection pooling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/8xx3tyca.aspx).

```c#
public static class SqlConnectionUtil
{
    public static string DefaultConnectionString { get; private set; }

    static SqlConnectionUtil()
    {
        SqlConnectionUril.DefaultConnectionString = 
                Properties.Settings.Default.TheConnectionString;
    }

    public static SqlConnection Create()
    {
        return new SqlConnection(SqlConnectionUtil.DefaultConnectionString);
    }
}
```

You would then use it like this.

```c#
using (var connection = SqlConnectionUtil.Create())
{
    using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
    {
        // do things.
    }
}
```

Comment: this can't be used in static

Comment: What do you mean? I edited a typo by the way, the constructor shouldn't have been declared as `public` (I didn't have time to try compile this).

Comment: `this.DefaultConnectionString` `this` shouldn't be there

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code for get coonection string

```
      var      defaultConn= new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["defaultConn"].ToString());
```