# How to define Sqlconnection Globally in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have defined connectionstring in web.config like this

```
<add name="connect" connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDatabase;User ID=sa;Password=mypassword" />
```

So I have to create Sqlconnection in each page inside class like this

```
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connect"].ConnectionString);
```

I don't want to create SqlConnection in each page. Is there any way to create sqlconnection only once and use it in every page ?

Comment: You probably would want to create a base class for every page which requires a connection, and place the creation connect in the base class to avoid repeat it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [in c# global connection to be used in all classes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174601/in-c-sharp-global-connection-to-be-used-in-all-classes)

Comment: That's probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are two ways:

1) Create BasePage class which has the code to create the connection in it... this will work best if you need a different connection for every user/session instance.

2) Create a static class with an initialize method and call it to the connection created and initialized on application_start

Here's an example of the static class with the application_Start

```
public static class Connections
{
     public static SqlConnection Connection {get; set;}
     public static Init()
     {
         //INIT YOUR CONNECTION PROPERTY HERE
         //Connection = new SqlConnection(....);
     }

}
```

IN GLOBAL.ASAX

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code that runs on application startup
    Connections.Init();
}
```

then in any ASP.Net back-end code you can reference/access it directly.

```
Connections.Connection
```

This is valid for the entire lifetime of the web application (Start to End)

Comment: HI @MaxOvrdrv   Thanks for your reply. Can you provide any sample code or reference please ?

Comment: Hi @MaxOvrdrv    Please can you tell me where should I define this "Public static class Connections" ?

Comment: this is a class... just create a new class in your project, and change the declaration to be static. it's a separate file...

Comment: Thanks. It's working fine. But one more thing I have to ask. I want to pass a parameter to Init function because I want to create dynamic connection like this.
 public static void Init(string Name)
     {
         Connection = new SqlConnection(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[Name].ConnectionString);
     }
But When I am trying to do that it's not working because Init function calls whenever application start and it does not let me define any variable to pass.

Comment: just create the `Init()` method with the parameter, and call it whenever you want to change the connection. Because it is named Init does not mean you can't call it again at a later time from a different place ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this desire output by

```
public class ConnectionHandler
{
    static SqlConnection con=null;
    public static SqlConnection ConnectionObj 
    {
        get
        {
         if(con==null)
             con=new SqlConnection("your connection string");
        return con;
     }
}
```

Latter on you can use this connection object like this

```
SqlConnection con=ConnectionHandler.ConnectionObj;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can store it inside `Application` dictionary as `Application["Connection"] = cn`.

Comment: Hi @Andrey Ischencko. Can you provide any sample code or reference ?

Comment: Assuming you have `SqlConnection` as you defined in question,
Saving: `Application["Connection"] = cn`;
Retrieving: `SqlConnection sc = Application["Connection"] as SqlConnection`

Answer (score 0):

```
private static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Services.Container.AddService(typeof(DbConnectionHandler),new DbConnectionHandler("connectionstring"));
        Services.Container.AddService(typeof(MyClass), new MyClass((DbConnectionHandler)Services.Container.GetService(typeof(DbConnectionHandler))));

        var myclass = (MyClass)Services.Container.GetService(typeof (MyClass));
        Console.WriteLine($"servicecontainertest {myclass.Testshit()}");

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    public static class Services
    {
        public static ServiceContainer Container { get; set; }
        static Services()
        {
            Container = new ServiceContainer();
        }
    }

    class MyClass
    {
        private DbConnectionHandler _dbHandler { get; set; }
        public MyClass(DbConnectionHandler dbhandler)
        {
            _dbHandler = dbhandler;
        }

        public string Testshit()
        {
            return _dbHandler.Connection.ConnectionString;
        }
    }
    class DbConnectionHandler
    {
        public SqlConnection Connection { get; set; }
        public DbConnectionHandler(string connection)
        {
            Connection = new SqlConnection(connection);
        }
    }
```

As you can see in my example i create a Global Service Class that contains a Servicecontainer, then adding Dbconnection to it, i can access it by using Services.Container.GetService() anywhere i want.