# Single declaration of connection string for whole application-ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have declared connection string in web.config file but i have also declared connection string in every aspx.cs page like

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ToString());
```

How to access the connection string from single declaration of web.config alone. I am new to programming.

Comment: Create a class with [constants](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/constants)/[static](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/static-classes-and-static-class-members) methods that retrieve the connection string from the config?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [in c# global connection to be used in all classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15174601/in-c-sharp-global-connection-to-be-used-in-all-classes)

Comment: @Adriani6 that class is already provided by the system `Properties.Settings.Default.MyConnectionString`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create some helper class for this and inside it read the value from the web.config and store it into a string variable (or constant):

Web.config file:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Server=...;initial catalog=...;persist security info=False;user id=...;password=...;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

In your code add new class:

```
using System.Configuration;
namespace MyProject.Common
{
    public class Constants
    {
        static public string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConnectionString"];
     }
}
```

Then you can access that from anywhere in your project.
Simply add using statement of the namespace that contains your new class and this is your value:

```
using MyProject.Common;
...
Constants.connectionString
```